# How to scrape wikipedia infobox and store it into a csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I already done scraping of wikipedia's infobox but I don't know how to store taht data in csv file. Please help me out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen


def infobox(query) :
    query = query
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+query
    raw = urlopen(url)
    soup = bs(raw)
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox vcard'})
    for tr in table.find_all('tr') :
        print(tr.text)
infobox('Infosys')
```

Comment: Can you write how you expect the CVS to look like, what are it's columns and rows, Are you obtaining for multiples rather than just Infosys, Are you expecting same number of outputs in each case? or Just manually create a csv with 3-5 rows and edit your question, then leave a comment tagging me and I will see

Comment: you are missing the th elements which give the left column. Was that intended?

Comment: I want one column for name and one column for its value

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect the required data and write in csv file, you can use csv module see below example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import urlopen
import csv


def infobox(query) :
    query = query
    content_list = []
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+query
    raw = urlopen(url)
    soup = bs(raw)
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox vcard'})
    for tr in table.find_all('tr') :
        if len(tr.contents) > 1:
            content_list.append([tr.contents[0].text.encode('utf-8'), tr.contents[1].text.encode('utf-8')])
        elif tr.text:
            content_list.append([tr.text.encode('utf-8')])
    write_csv_file(content_list)

def write_csv_file(content_list):
    with open(r'd:\Test.csv', mode='wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(content_list)

infobox('Infosys')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how you can test whether the row has a header and a table cell element within it to ensure two columns (you can expand to write td only rows to populate perhaps the first column within the if structure). I use slightly different encoding syntax for cleaner output, `select` for faster element selection than find and utilize pandas to generate the csv.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+ 'Infosys'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', 'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/'}
r = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
table =soup.select_one('.infobox.vcard')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
output = []
for row in rows:
    if len(row.select('th, td')) == 2:
        outputRow = [row.select_one('th').text, row.select_one('td').text, [item['href'] for item in row.select('td a')] if row.select_one('td a') is not None else '']
        outputRow[2] = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infosys' + item if item[0] == '#' else 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + item for item in outputRow[2]]
        output.append(outputRow)
df = pd.DataFrame(output)    
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: i want the hyperlinks in infobox should be displayed in the csv file

Comment: I have added a draft of how to handle adding the appropriate prefix to each href. You would need to validate.